# jquery filter table but exclude one column

Tags: jquery, search, filter

I'm using a script that I found to search in my table and show only the rows that contains the rows which matches the text in the search input field.

```
      $("#searchfahrzeuge").keyup(function(){

      $("#fahrzeugliste").find("tr").hide();
      var data = this.value.split(" ");
      var jo = $("#fahrzeugliste").find("tr");


      $.each(data, function(i, v){
          jo = jo.filter("*:containsIgnoreCase('"+v+"')");
        console.log(jo);
      });

      jo.show(); });
```

But now I want to exclude  two columns of the table, they have both have a class ".nosearch",
but I don't know how do to this...

I tried:

```
var jo = $("#fahrzeugliste").find("tr:not(.nosearch)");
```

and also in the filter function:

```
jo = jo.filter("*:not(.nosearch):containsIgnoreCase('"+v+"')");
```

but both doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide your html, but I assume the class is on the `td`.  This is your problem, the filtering is all done at the `tr` level so the `:not` is applying to the `tr`, which does not have the class.

I would change it to filter on the `td`s rather than the `tr` elements.  Something like this (untested):

```
  var jo = $("#fahrzeugliste").find("tr > td");

  $.each(data, function(i, v){
      jo = jo.filter(":not(.nosearch):containsIgnoreCase('"+v+"')");
  });

  jo.parent().show(); // show the tr's for all matched tds
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. i ran into similar problem a while ago. this is solution what i can up with. it not that fancy but it works.

```
<input id="searchfahrzeuge" placeholder="Search for" >

<table id='fahrzeugliste'>

       <tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Email</th></tr>

    <tbody>

       <tr><td>Adykn</td><td>Lovejoy</td><td class='nosearch'>Me@lovejoy.com</td></tr>

       <tr><td>Adam</td><td>Smith</td><td class='nosearch'>Adam@lovejoy.com</td></tr>

       <tr><td>Joe</td><td>Eddie</td><td class='nosearch'>Eddie@lovejoy.com</td></tr>

    </tbody>  

</table>
```

---

```
<script> 
  $(document).ready(function () {
                       $('#searchfahrzeuge').keyup(function() {
                        var that = this;

                        var tableBody = $('#fahrzeugliste tbody');
                        var tr = $('#fahrzeugliste tbody tr');
                        $('.search-sf').remove();
                        $("#fahrzeugliste tr td:not(.nosearch)").each(function (i,val) {
                            var tableRowsClass = $(this).closest('tr');


                            var rowText = $(val).text().toLowerCase();
                            var inputText = $(that).val().toLowerCase();

                            if (inputText !== '') {
                                $('.search-query-sf').remove();
                                tableBody.prepend('<tr class="search-query-sf"><td colspan="3"><strong>Searching for: "' +$(that).val() +'"</strong></td></tr>');
                            } else {
                                $('.search-query-sf').remove();
                            }

                            if (rowText.indexOf(inputText) === -1) {
                                tableRowsClass.hide();
                            } else {
                                $('.search-sf').remove();
                                $('.dtrc').hide();
                                tableRowsClass.show();
                            }
                        });

                        if (tr.children(':visible').length === 0) {
                            tableBody.append('<tr class="search-sf"><td class="text-muted" colspan="3">No entries found.</td></tr>');
                        }
                    });
                });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always just run the search you have now, and then just use

```
$('.nosearch').hide();
```

afterwards, instead of trying to make your query overly complicated.

Comment: This would hide the individual cells, which would just cause a mess.

Comment: I'm sorry,you said "exclude 2 colums of the table, they have booth have a class ".nosearch" ", so maybe I'm confused, do the TDs or TRs have the class?

Comment: He didn't include the html but `tr`s are rows, not columns.

Answer (score 0):

What about a custom function for filter

```
var jo = $("#fahrzeugliste tr")
.filter(":containsIgnoreCase('"+v+"')")
.filter(function(i){
    if(!$(this).children('td').hasClass('nosearch'))
    return $(this);
});
```

[Like this one](http://jsfiddle.net/vprpc/2/). Could be useful when you really need rows.